# Check for point inside/outside in concave 3d model

Tags: computational-geometry, vtk

What is best way to find given 3d Point is inside/outside in concave/convex model ?

I tried vtkSelectEnclosedPoints but it seems it can only handle convex case.

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the topic of Section 7.5 in [*Computational Geometry in C*](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html). The problem is generally called "Point in Polyhedron." It is not a straightforward issue, but it is by now well-explored. Code is available for the computation at the book link.

At a high level, one shoots a ray from the point *p* and counts intersections: if odd, then *p* is inside; if even, outside. But there are delicate issues about how to "count" correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Rayshooting, as already suggested. A spatial search structure like an R-Tree will speed up the search. Make sure you don't hit low dimensional elements (edges and vertices) or the hit count may be wrong. An alternative to counting the hits is to find the closest pierced triangle. Then check if the angle enclosed by the direction of the ray and the normal vector of the pierced triangle is less or more than 90 degrees. Numeric issues are a problem for both versions, you may want to use multi-precision number type if robustness is vital.